# Marshaling from C# to C++

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke

I am new to C# and visual studio. I have a C# GUI that passes parameters to functions exported from a C++ DLL. The platform in Visual Studio 2005.

I have a function in the c++ DLL that take parameters of the following types:
UINT8
UINT16
LPCWSTR
someword (the following has been defined in the c+= dll : typedef void* someword..so basically someword is just a void pointer.)

Can you please help me how do i pass parameters from my C# GUI to this function imported from the DLL. I know it has to be done using MarshalAs but i donno how. also the c++ dll is unmanaged. Any help would be apreciated.

Thanks,
Viren

Comment: @Viren: can you please provide the exact definition of the function (in the C++ DLL)?

Comment: sure..it is as follows:

int function (someword somevariable,UINT16 var1,UINT8 var2,UINT8 var3,UINT8 var4,LPCWSTR str1, LPCWSTR str2);

Comment: Well, since you mention someword has been defined as a void* it is very important what that void pointer will be pointing to (what type of structure that is), or otherwise if ti's just a "pass-through" pointer, you could use a IntPtr variable to represent the pointer address.. Still, the point is that some more clarity is necessary for a complete answer!

Comment: well its just a pass through pointer I think..i do not have access to the code right now but will tell you exactly what it is pointing to in the evening..
thanks a lot for your quick replies..I shall try using IntPtr to see if that works..

Comment: I tried using IntPtr and it worked fine..no problems with IntPtr..thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
[DllImport("lib.dll")]
public static extern int FunctionName(IntPtr somevariable, ushort var1, byte var2, byte var3, byte var4, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr), In] string str1, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr), In] string str2);
```

Comment: thanks..btw i am importing the dll using the following statement:
[DllImport("lib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]

so is the 'charset' going to make a difference to what you suggested earlier??

Comment: I think it should work properly if you will explicitly tell how to marshal each string, but I'd check just to make sure and start worrying if it's not :).

Answer (score 1):

Could you help us out by providing the signature of the C++ DLL?  For the types you specified, here are the correct types

- UINT8: UInt8
- UINT16: UInt16
- LPCWSTR: String (make sure to use the [In] Marshal attribute on the parameter as well)

Have you checked out the PInvoke Interop Assistant yet?  It was designed to help people through these scenarios by converting C++ signatures into the equivalent DLL import

- http://www.codeplex.com/clrinterop/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=14120

Comment: thanks JaredPar for the link..I used byte, ushort and string for the types respectively and it works fine..

Comment: byte is just a shorcut for System.UInt8, ushort - for System.UInt16, and string for System.String, so you are closer to JaredPar's solution that you think ;-).